# Rotate a curve by an angle

Tags: geometry

I’m trying to find an equation of a rotated curve about the origin and I’m confused about an issue, hoping for some help.

So to rotate a point $(x,y)$ about the origin counter clockwise by theta, we use the following mapping

$X\to \cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)$

$Y\to x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)$

For example if I want to rotate by 90 degrees counterclockwise then the mapping becomes:

$(x,y)\to (-y,x)$

Now, if I have the curve $y= x^2+3x$ and If I want to rotate it by 90 degrees counter clockwise with respect to the origin, I replace x with -y, and y with x. The equation of the rotated curve becomes:

$X=y^2-3y$

Now if I graph the rotated curve, I see that its rotated by 90 degrees clockwise, and not counterclockwise!!where is my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the original curve is given by $f(x,y) = 0$.  The image a point $(x, y)$ on this curve is $(x', y') = (x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta, x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta)$.  Since we want the relation between $x'$, and $y'$ and we only have the relation between $x$ and $y$, we have write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $x'$ and $y'$, then plug these expressions into $f(x,y)=0$.  From the above expressions, it follows that,

$ x = \cos \theta  x' + \sin \theta y' $

and

$ y = -\sin \theta x' + \cos \theta y' $

And then just plug in these expressions into $f(x,y) = 0$ to get the relation between $x'$ and $y'$.  So with your example, $y = x^2 + 3 x$, and $\theta = 90^\circ$, hence

$x = 0 \cdot x' + 1 \cdot y' = y'$ and $ y = -1 \cdot x' + 0 \cdot y' = -x' $

Plug these in, you get

$ - x' = y'^2 + 3 y' $

so that

$ x' = - y'^2 - 3y' $

Finally, replacing $x'$ and $y'$ with the standard names of the variables
we get $ x = - y^2 - 3 y $  as the equation of the rotated curve.

Comment: Thank you, now it does make more sense. 

One more question please, why the reflection transformation mapping works and not the rotation. 

For example, if I want to reflect the graph with respect to x-axis  then the mapping is(x,y)—>(x,-y). When I replace y with -y  in the equation,I will get the correct reflected equation. Why the mapping with rotation does not work like reflection?

Comment: Unlike rotations where the inverse of a rotation by an angle $\theta$ is a rotation by an angle $(-\theta)$, reflections are their own inverses, Thus if vector $y = F x$ where $F$ is the reflection matrix, then $x = F^{-1} y$, however in this case from the nature of reflection, $F^{-1} = F$.

Comment: You rock !! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to plug in the inverse of your coordinate transformation. The reason is that if $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the original curve, then you want $(-y_0,x_0)$ to lie on the new curve. $(y,-x)$ is the inverse transformation, so we get the equation $-x=y^2+3y$. Now if you plug in $(-y_0,x_0)$ you get $y_0=x_0^2+3x_0$ which is true because $(x_0,y_0)$ belongs to the first curve.

The idea of plugging in the inverse transformation is that when you then plug in your point, it now cancels out with the inverse and you get your old curve back.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was bugging me for days !!